# Find The Highest Score In Each Row Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

In order to train my coding foo, I have decide to register on the CodeEval platform. I stumble upon an exercise which I thought was pretty simple, but some reason, there is a bug that I cannot resolve since a long time ago. 
Here's the situation (I've put only what seem to be more important from the text):

"the participants calculated votes that they received for each painting and inserted them in the table. But, they could not determine which movement has won and whose work received the highest score, so they asked you to help. 
You need to determine and print the highest score of each category in the table."
More on the exercice on the following link : 
https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/208/

This is a sample input that the platform uses to verify that my algorithm is OK:

```
333 967 860 -742 -279 -905 | 
-922 380 -127 630 38 -548 | 
258 -522 157 -580 357 -502 | 
963 486 909 -416 -936 -239 | 
517 571 107 -676 531 -782 | 
542 265 -171 251 -93 -638
```

Here's my output from this sample : 
967 630 357 963 571

At first, I couldn't understand what was wrong. But it seems that after the last 
"|", my code freezes and "jumps" on the second line from the file I'm reading. My code looked pretty ok for what I was doing.

Here is the sample code :

```
//Sample code to read in test cases:
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System;
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(args[0]))
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (null == line)
                        continue;

                    List<int> highestScores = new List<int>();
                    var temporaryNumbers = new List<int>();
                    string[] splittedLine = line.Split(' ');
                    foreach (var s in splittedLine)
                    {
                        if (s == "|")
                        {
                            highestScores.Add(temporaryNumbers.Max());
                            temporaryNumbers.Clear();
                            continue;
                        }
                        int value;
                        if (int.TryParse(s, out value))
                        {
                            temporaryNumbers.Add(value);
                            continue; 
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(highestScores.Count == 0)
                        continue; 

                    var newLine = highestScores.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, value)=> current + (value + " "));
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(newLine);
                }
        }
    }
```

I guess my question would how to fix a situation like this ? It's not jump one line from the input that they use, it's every line. At the last |, the code jumps to the next line, if ever there is one.

Comment: Can you explain the input format a little more? Is the `|` supposed to mark the end of a row? Are the numbers supposed to be columns?

Comment: So sorry, yes I should have explained that. " Table rows are separated by pipes '|'. All table rows contain scores for each category, so all lines are of an equal length."

Comment: Just found out that I was looking for the end of my iteration, doing so, I simply never calling max on the last table row...

Comment: I think you are mis-reading the question. It looks like you are trying to find the highest score *in each row*, when looking at the link it looks like you are supposed to be finding the highest score *in each column*. So with your sample data, the result should be (by inspection, I might mess this up): `963,967,909,630,531,-239`

Comment: You're right, I have updated my link, so it can be better understood! I have sorry for confusing the readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In broad strokes, this is how I'd go about handling this:

First split your string into rows using `Split("|")` (let's call the resulting array `rows`). Now create a `List<int>` called `columnMax`. Now loop through `rows` and for each row we will `Split(" ")` (let's call this `cells`). Now we know (from the original assignment) that we can assume that rows are all the same length, so we will loop through `cells` using a `for` loop and check:

```
var value = int.Parse(cells[i]);    // leaving out error checking for now
                                    // but you could use TryParse to catch bad data
if (columnMax.Count <= i)
{
     columnMax.Add(value);
}
else if (columnMax[i] < value)
{
     columnMax[i] = value;
}
```

Now at the end of your loop, `columnMax` should contain all the maximums for each column (i.e. category).

Just for kicks, here's a Linq solution:

```
var maximums = input.Split(new [] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Aggregate((IEnumerable<int>)null,(m,r) => 
    {
        var cells = r.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(c => int.Parse(c));
        return m == null ? cells : cells.Zip(m, Math.Max);
    });
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you'd create a first loop to go through the rows after splitting on the "|". Then while looping on the rows (1..N) you'd look on each cell of a single row (1..N) with a second for loop ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have one loop (going through the cells) nested inside another loop (that goes through the rows).

Comment: I don't wanna sound bad or anything because you're giving me advice and I appreciate it. But I'm wondering, considering the time and space complexity (not that it's relevant in this situation), wouldn't my solution with a single for loop work better? 
It's just a question, I'm really wondering. (Trying to get a grisp of those notions)

Comment: @KevinAvignon: No. You are still going to examine the *exact same number of cells* whether you treat it as a 2D array or a flat 1D array. There is no way around hitting all `36` numbers in your input.

Comment: Oh then I went through all that hustle for nothing haha ! Thanks for your input Matt !

Comment: using just the var maximums would give me what I want :O 
That is neat.
Thanks Matt ! :-)

Comment: I just dont get the final part of your Linq expression : " cells.Zip(m, (a,b) => Math.Max(a,b) "
It worked just fine, but it's more about me trying to understand it so I might use something like this in the future

Comment: @KevinAvignon: [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx): `Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.`. The function here is `Math.Max` (note, I edited it because I don't even need the anonymous function).

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post the whole solution, but as I see is a contest where you're participating.

So this is my help:

Try to split your problem in little problems and resolve one thing at a time. Actually your code is a little bit messi.

At first create a method to load all file entries and return a string collection with people scores for each line in the file . This would require a few more methods to convert string[] to int[], like this one.

```cs
static void StringToIntegers()
{
    var input = "333 967 860 -742 -279 -905 | -922 380 -127 630 38 -548 | 258 -522 157 -580 357 -502 | 963 486 909 -416 -936 -239 | 517 571 107 -676 531 -782 | 542 265 -171 251 -93 -638";

    var primaryArray = input.Split('|');

    foreach (var block in primaryArray)
    {
        var trimmedBlock = block.Trim();
        var secondaryArray = trimmedBlock.Split(' ');

        var intArray = StringArrToIntArr(secondaryArray);
    }
}

private static int[] StringArrToIntArr(string[] secondaryArray)
{

    int[] intArray = new int[secondaryArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < secondaryArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(secondaryArray[i], out intArray[i]))
            throw new FormatException(string.Format("The string {0} is not a compatible int type", 
                secondaryArray[i]));
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

Then for each  int collection call a method able to group each category score in  different int arrays and there you can return the max number for each one.

Comment: You're right, my code is indeed messy. 
I was just coding for coding without taking in consideration best practices. Which I know I should've done.. 
Your solution looks super ! Thanks for the consideration you took !

Comment: Looking at it quickly, I'd need a third int array to store each max values, no? Because your intArray just seems to store locally within the foreach loop. Or am I reading wrong ?

Comment: Sure! I didn't put the whole solution because I know you want to do it yourself!! My advice: practices aren't just good for 'professional' code, a structured and modular code will give you a great code base to resolve your needings in an easy way.